# How to create a free standing patch without source control?

Tags: diff, solaris, patch

I need to patch [libidn2](https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/libidn2/manual/libidn2.html) on Solaris. libidn2 was fetched from GNU's website with wget. Its not provided by Sun and its not in source control.

The library does not use `glibc`, and it does not have the function `error (int status, int errnum, const char *format, ...)`. I made a copy of the original source file and I have a diff with a similar function:

```
solaris:libidn2-0.16$ diff -u src/idn2.c.bu src/idn2.c
--- src/idn2.c.bu       2017-03-29 00:20:08.621934160 -0400
+++ src/idn2.c  2017-03-29 01:25:12.488402745 -0400
@@ -31,7 +31,9 @@
 #include <unistr.h>

 /* Gnulib headers. */
+#ifndef __sun__
 #include "error.h"
+#endif
 #include "gettext.h"
 #define _(String) dgettext (PACKAGE, String)
 #include "progname.h"
@@ -48,6 +50,18 @@
      year.  */
   "Copyright %s %d Simon Josefsson.";

+#if defined(__sun__)
+static void
+error (int status, int errnum, const char *format, ...)
+{
+    va_list args;
+    va_start(args, format);
+    vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
+    va_end(args);
+    exit(status);
+}
+#endif
+
 static void
 usage (int status)
 {
```

I've been reading through the [`diff(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) and [`patch(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) man pages, but I'm not quite getting what needs to be done. I don't believe I've found a discussion of the task (maybe I am not seeing the forest through the trees).

My question is, how can I turn this into a free standing patch? That is, how can I turn it into something to apply after a fresh download and unpack of libidn2?

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the correct answer, but the quote won't fit into a comment, and my experience with `patch` is that the output from `diff` *is* the "freestanding patch".

You can run `patch --dry-run  < your.diff.output` from most likely the base directory of the expanded libidn2 source tarball to see what *would* happen if you apply your diff output with `patch`.

In my installed copy of Solaris 11, `patch` appears to be GNU patch as it has the `--dry-run` option.  [The Solaris 11.2 `patch` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/patch-1g.html#scrolltoc) has this excerpt for creating patches:

> **NOTES FOR PATCH SENDERS**
>
> There are several things you should bear in mind if you  are
>        going to be sending out patches.
>
> Create your patch systematically.  A good method is the command  `diff -Naur old new`  where `old` and `new` identify the old
>        and new directories.  The names old and new should not  contain  any  slashes.   The diff command's headers should have
>        dates and times in Universal  Time  using  traditional  Unix
>        format, so that patch recipients can use the -Z or --set-utc
>        option.  Here is an example command, using Bourne shell syn-
>        tax:
>
> ```
>                 LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0 diff -Naur gcc-2.7 gcc-2.8
> ```
>
> Tell your recipients how to apply the patch by telling  them
>        which  directory  to  cd to, and which patch options to use.
>        The option string `-Np1` is recommended.  Test your  procedure
>        by pretending to be a recipient and applying your patch to a
>        copy of the original files.
>
> ...

Answer (score -2):

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your core problem is "currently I am applying a patch to the libidn2 source which I want to redo later for future releases of libidn2", right? *This is exactly what you want to use source code control for!* Just because the upstream source is not fetched from a source code control repository, it does not mean that you cannot put into one yourself:

```
$ mkdir libidn2-source; cd libidn2-source
$ git init
$ git checkout -b upstream
$ wget https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/libidn/libidn2-0.16.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf libidn2-0.16.tar.gz && rm libidn2-0.16.tar.gz
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Upstream libidn2-0.16.tar.gz"
$ git checkout -b downstream
$ cp /the/file/in/the/question/src/idn2.c src/idn2.c
$ git add src/idn2.c
$ git commit -m "Added sun specific error fallback function"

# In the future...
$ git checkout upstream
$ wget https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/libidn/libidn2-latestgreatest.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf libidn2-latestgreatest.tar.gz && rm libidn2-latestgreatest.tar.gz
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Upstream libidn2-latestgreatest.tar.gz"

# Now for the "apply after a fresh download and unpack of libidn2" part:
$ git rebase upstream downstream
```

Notice the lack of any keep track of and update free standing patch file here.

---

The source seems to be available in a [git repo](https://gitlab.com/libidn/libidn2), so you might just clone that instead of downloading and checking in tar files, but the rebase part will be exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks. Checking out from Git is not in the workflow. in fact, the script is intended to be run on CentOS 5 and Fedora 10. The script installs Git on machines that don't have it. Once the initial script was written it was pointed towards Solaris. Oracle provides a very old Git (Solaris 11) or no Git at all (Solaris 10). Oracle charges folks to allow access to their updated Git.

Comment: But git is still the answer to "how can I turn this into a free standing patch?". You do not need to have git installed on the Solaris machines, just store it on one of the Centos/Fedora machines and then when you need the patch for one of the Solaris machines you run `git format-patch upstream downstream` and it will create an up to date, free standing patch which you than can apply with the patch(1) program.